# iPhone in-app product contents example

Tags: iphone, in-app

I'm trying to implement an in-app purchase to open new features in an iPhone app.  Can anyone give an example of a product file that provides this kind of capability?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a great tutorial on non-consumable (e.g: unlockable features) in-app purchases [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial). For consumables (e.g: in-game currency), go [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23266/in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial-consumables-and-receipt-validation).